# How can scroll calendar horizontally on React Native like Way of Life App. you can see a video by the link

Tags: react-native, horizontal-scrolling, android-calendar

you can see on google drive
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UWUfli7g5vlh25PNHbGR46Cs6weROdQV

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GpR7.png)

Comment: Please be more explicit. What do you want exactly? You want the scroll function to snap to the beginning of the week?

Comment: I am using <Flatlist horizontal={true} /> but it's just scrolling. I couldn't fixed one by one calendar screen. Is it possible to fixed screen by Flatlist. In 'Way of life' app when it scrolls then it gets next calendar page and prev page disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to use `Flatlist`? Do you have a small number of items to display? If you have a small list, you can switch to `<ScrollView>` and use `snapToAlignment={VALUE}` or `snapToInterval={NUMBER}` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#snaptointerval